# Passing Mac address of bluetooth to other activity

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

[debug image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNqqd.jpg)**BluetoothActivity.Java**
 [debug image 2][2]

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_main);
        //myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);
        toggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue = (String) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                String MAC = itemValue.substring(itemValue.length() - 17);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Bluetooth_dataDisplay.class);
                intent.putExtra("MAC",MAC);
                startActivity(intent);
                //BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
                // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
                //ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);
                //t.start();
            }
        });

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        //verify bluetooth is supported on the device
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // Device does not support Bluetooth
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        }

    }//end oncreate
```

**Bluetooth_datadisplay.Java**[bluetooth_datadisplay image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mfe45.jpg)

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_datadisplay);

        myLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.label);

        String MAC = getIntent().getStringExtra("MAC");

        BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);

        // Initiate a connection request in a separate thread
        ConnectingThread t = new ConnectingThread(bluetoothDevice);

        t.start();

    }//end oncreate
```

**Error**

Attempt to invoke virtual method '`android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)`' on a null object reference

Hi I trying to pass the Mac address of the bluetooth to bluetooth datadisplay. But I got the above error. Can anyone explain to me what wrong? Thank you!

Comment: use a debugger and check the value of `String MAC`

Comment: @jhamon Hi! I had used a debugger and checked. I think is char? I try to call  char[] MAC = getIntent().getCharArrayExtra("MAC");
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(String.valueOf(MAC)); But is wrong I think. I attached two images call debug image here and debug image 2. Thank you

Comment: Hi @AndroidDev by any chance do you know what happened here?

Comment: As the method throwing the exception is `getRemoteDevice`you should check the `String MAC` value in the `Bluetooth_datadisplay` class. Also, check `mAdapter`

Comment: @jhamon Hi! My madapter is null. and string Mac is in char I think. I uploaded the bluetooth_datadisplay image above. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have not defined object** of **mAdapter**.

```
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi it helped thanks! So I need to declare it everytime on a new activity?

Comment: @Spotty, thanks for appreciation, Yes you have to do.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know! :)